# Relation between building blocks and group generator

Tags: group-theory

Say you have a system where $a$ is used to build $b$, $b$ is used to build $c$, etc. In terms of group theory, say the operation is "combine" $*$. (Not sure if this would be considered a group yet, but at least a semigroup)

\begin{align}
a * a &\rightarrow b\\
b * b &\rightarrow c\\
 &\dotsc\\
x * x &\rightarrow y\\
y * y &\rightarrow z
\end{align}

The question is if $a$ would be considered the generating set, since it is used to build everything else, or if everything up to $y$ would be considered the generating set.

Comment: I'm not sure that it is a semigroup yet.  What would $a^3$ or $bc$ mean?  You seem only to define squares.  In short, have you really given an operation on your set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about how your group / set is defined, but certainly $a$ alone already generates all the elements you have listed: they are all of the form $a^{2^n}$. Of course, there are also other elements, like $a^3=a*b=b*a$,...

Comment: Thank you. Yeah was just wondering about the generator part, because technically they all generate stuff.

Comment: Yes, sure, the set of generators of a group is not unique. For instance, $$\mathbb{F}_5 = \{0,1,2,3,4\}=\langle 1\rangle = \langle 1,2 \rangle = \dots$$ any subset except $\{0\}$ generates it (additively)